# OutputCache Flush Cache through an Action in an MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, action, outputcache

In many actions from the MVC application we are building up, we use OutputCache as follows:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom = "language")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
   //Action..
}
```

So, I want to have an action where I can flush manually all these caches:

```
  public ActionResult RefrescarCache()
        {
            var keys = HttpContext.Cache.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList();

            keys.ForEach(k => HttpContext.Cache.Remove(k.Key.ToString()));
            ViewBag.operationResult= "The cache was flushed succesfully!";

            return View();
        }
```

The thing, that it seems to not work. I will aprecciate any idea or advice you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.removeoutputcacheitem.aspx

Comment: It seems to be specific for only one url, is there any way to do it for all?

Comment: I'm tearing my hair out with this one... RemoveOutputCacheItem is appallingly basic

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 2):

We've had the same problem and the only solution which was working was with:

`HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url)`

like Giedrius already mentioned.

Comment: Is there any way to do it for all the urls ?

Comment: Are the cached urls saved in an array/object someplace?

Comment: Guess we'll never know

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone is asking for a way to clear the all the url´s...

I can think of two ways:

1- painfull but easy, maintain an array of virtual paths to be clean.

```
foreach(string path in myArray){HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(path); }
```

2- Uses reflection to get everything, example here: 
[list OutputCache entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156792/list-outputcache-entry)

I think this is dificult because it´s not ASP.NET caching the pages, but IIS (7+) kernel cache.