# OutputCache and missing "_caches" field

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

I'm trying to use the code seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156792/list-outputcache-entry).  When I try to execute this line

```
FieldInfo cachesInfo = cache.GetType().GetField("_caches", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

cachesInfo ends up being null.  I added a foreach loop to look at the object and my results show no field called "_caches".

```
_entries
_expires
_usage
_lock
_disposed
_totalCount
_publicCount
_maxCount
_maxCountOverload
_flushUndercount
_insertBlock
_useInsertBlock
_insertBlockCalls
_utcLastTrimCompleted
_iSubCache
_cacheMultiple
_cacheCommon
```

I'm using the code as is in the link.  What is it that I'm missing?

(Warning: I am woefully ignorant on this subject but have been tasked with figuring it out.  I know cachesInfo is null, I know I'm not seeing "_caches", but I don't know why).

Thanks greatly for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a difference in .Net versions.  See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/05/reading-all-users-session.aspx).  The field "_caches" exists in .Net 3.5.  I changed my code to look more like the .Net 2.0 example (using "_entries") and it works.